# Why when i am searching for something else is deleting the previous contents?

Tags: javascript

Why when you are searching for something else is deleting the previous contents ?For example first you search for egg and show the contents but then when you search for beef the program deletes the egg and shows only beef.Thank you for your time code:

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');
const mealList = document.getElementById('meal');
const mealDetailsContent = document.querySelector('.meal-details-content');
const recipeCloseBtn = document.getElementById('recipe-close-btn');

// event listeners
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', getMealList);
mealList.addEventListener('click', getMealRecipe);
recipeCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mealDetailsContent.parentElement.classList.remove('showRecipe');
});


// get meal list that matches with the ingredients
function getMealList(){
    let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();
    fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${searchInputTxt}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        let html = "";
        if(data.meals){
            data.meals.forEach(meal => {
                html += `
                    <div class = "meal-item" data-id = "${meal.idMeal}">
                        <div class = "meal-img">
                            <img src = "${meal.strMealThumb}" alt = "food">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "meal-name">
                            <h3>${meal.strMeal}</h3>
                            <a href = "#" class = "recipe-btn">Get Recipe</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
            });
            mealList.classList.remove('notFound');
        } else{
            html = "Sorry, we didn't find any meal!";
            mealList.classList.add('notFound');
        }

        mealList.innerHTML = html;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse you are using innerHTML , if you want to save the previous contents you should use append or innerHTML + = .

Answer (score 1):

Because everytime you make a search, the html var is populated with new data.
if you move the 'html' variable to the root scope, this should get you there:

```
// get meal list that matches with the ingredients
let html = ""; // <-- place it outside the function body
function getMealList(){
    let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();
    fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${searchInputTxt}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // let html = ""; // <-- remove it from here
        if(data.meals){
            data.meals.forEach(meal => {
```